# How to save octet stream received as REST response to the file system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, unirest, octetstring

While trying to save `octet stream` JSON format response (containing data of file in a properietary format) received using `Unirest client` the format gets corrupted and the (properietary) software used to open that format is unable to open this saved file. `Data encoding mismatch` error is received.

The same **works perfectly fine** when the REST call is driven **via** nodejs based **POSTMAN** chrome app.

Any clues or leads to this.

Following is the code used to receive octet stream in nodejs:

```
urClient.get(url)
    .header('Authorization', '<token>')
    .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .end(
        function(response) {
            log.info('+++++++++++++++'+response.code);
            //log.info('+++++++++++++++'+response);
            //log.info('+++++++++++++++'+response.body);
            //log.info('+++++++++++++++'+response.keys);
            fs.writeFile(`${destination}\\${fileName}.${fileExtension}`, response.data, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    response = {
                        "error": error
                    };
                    res.statusCode = 400;
                    res.json(response); }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of data, the stream needs to be used to be written into a file.

The following works:

```
fs.writeFile(`response.txt`, response.stream, function (error) {
  if (error) { console.error(error); }
});
```